# Compare two sigmoid shape curves

Tags: statistical-significance, sigmoid-curve

I have `x` and `y`-values for two sigmoid curves (probit). `x`-values are the same for both curves, but the `y`-values are different. I now wish to compare these two to see if there is a significant difference between them. Which test should I use for that when it's sigmoid curves ?

I can do it in Python or R, doesn't matter.

UPDATE (image of the curve):
[image]

Comment: If they are standard sigmoids, then won't they be exactly same. Do your curves have noise?

Comment: With noise you mean that the curve is not smooth ? If that is the case, then no, they don't have noise. I have attached an image of what it looks like (yes, there are more than one curve in this case, sorry for that, but I only need to compare two at a time).

Comment: What are the dashed lines right next to the standard lines?

Comment: In principle just a variety of the other lines. What I actually need to compare is the dashed lines to each other, and the solid lines. Not dashed vs solid.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the graph, but essentially, if you've got two curves $y_1, y_2$ that are the logistic transformations of a linear predictor that depends on a variable $x$:

$$y = \frac{1}{1+exp(-(a + bx))}$$

... you can invert the transformation by using the logit function $ln \left( \frac{y}{1-y} \right)$ to get back the linear predictor $a+bx$. You could then compare the coefficients $a, b$.

If there's no noise, then there's no question of *significance*, if the curves are not the same, they're different! There's probably no standardised 'test' for comparing sigmoid curves - the question as it is, isn't statistically well-framed for any sort of *test* to exist.